# flutter sqflite encryption on windows application

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqlcipher, flutter-windows

I'm using flutter to build an application for both windows and android.
My app must have a secure database, I use sqflite_sqlcipher for android and have already implemented many functions upon the database.

for the windows version I also need a secure sqlite based database but only thing I found so far is sqflite_commmon_ffi which supports windows crud operations on sqlite but does not support encrypting data base.

can you guys please advice solutions to have encrypted sqlite base data base on windows version of flutter.
p.s: already encrypted vital data before inserting into database but I need an extra layer of security.
thanks in advance.